# If and for loops in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a diamond dataset that contains variable "price". I want to create additional variable called "price_range" based on the information provided in variable price. I created the following loop:

```
diamonds$price_range <- for (diamonds$price in 1:length(diamonds$price)){
  if (diamonds$price<= 500) {
    diamonds$price_range="not expensive"
  } else if (diamonds$price > 500 & diamonds$price <=1000) {
    diamonds$price_range="affordable price"
  } else{
    diamonds$price_range="expensive"
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my loop? How would I fix it to make it work in R?

Comment: 1) use "=" instead of "==" 2) use indexing to avoid overwriting and dont assign the for loop to the variable

Comment: have a look at function `cut`

Comment: @TonioLiebrand http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html#style-syn & https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#assignment: _Use `<-`, not `=`, for assignment._

Comment: @UweBlock. Given the code provided I would put the focus on working code, in favour of fitting to coding style preferences. If the question is do you prefer "=" or "<-" I might even join your side ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because R used element-by-element operations, you could also do this with a nested `ifelse` statement and save the trouble of making a loop

```
diamonds$price_range <- ifelse(diamonds$price <= 500, "not expensive", 
   ifelse(c(diamonds$price > 500 & diamonds$price <=1000), "affordable price", "expensive"))

table(diamonds$price_range)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the option! This works. Howerever, I still would like to know why my code wouldn't work.

Comment: @DashaBazueva you want to avoid using loops in R whenever possible. If you look at the structure of your loop it's not actually looping through the data.

Comment: try:
    for (diamonds$price in 1:length(diamonds$price)){
    print(diamonds$price)
    }

compared to:
    for (i in 1:length(diamonds[,1])){
    print(diamonds[i,7])
    }

the second loop changes the row index each time you go through the loop and give you the price, you could take that price with your if statements and the above comments to do what you want. If your question is solved, make sure to mark and upvote the answer. welcome to SO

Comment: @DashaBazueva there are a lot of reasons why your code does not work. The index inside the `for` call is wrong, then you try to assign using a comparison function (`==`), `if` is not vectorised and you try to use it as if it was.................